# geckodriver not launching firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, codeception, geckodriver

I am using firefox v 48.0.2 and am trying to get my selenium (selenium-server v2.53) remotedriver automated tests to run on firefox, I have geckodriver 0.9.0 installed and when i go through the documentation on the github readme and run this command: (on mac osx 10.11.3)

```
geckodriver -b /Applications/FirefoxNightly.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
```

i get this error message:

> thread '< main >' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Io(Error { repr: Os { code: 48, message: "Address already in use" } })', ../src/libcore/result.rs:746
>   note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.

ive tried ignoring this step but when i run my tests firefox does not launch, i have ensured that my webdriver capabilities include `marrionette: true`

```
WebDriver:
  browser: 'firefox'
  clear_cookies: false
  restart: false
  window_size: 414x736
  marionette: true
```

other than that i can not find any documentation to lead me in the correct direction, did i perhaps over look something? any help is greatly appreciated!

I am also using codeception to handle my tests (php)

**EDIT**

I was able to get this command to work after killing the process that was listening on port 4444:

```
geckodriver -b /Applications/FirefoxNightly.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
```

But even with that running Firefox is still not launching

Comment: `ive tried ignoring this step but when i run my tests firefox does not launch`, what is the exception occurred this time??

Comment: no exception @SaurabhGaur the test execution begins, but because the browser does not launch, it cannot find anything on the screen